# async and await together

Tags: c#, async-await

```cs
async Task Task_MethodAsync() { /* . . . */ }
await Task_MethodAsync();
```

How can we combine them in one block where `anonymous async task` trails `await` keyword, which looks like below?

```cs
await async Task { /* . . . */ };
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, as it currently makes no sense. What does *anonymous async Task* mean?

Comment: Trying to turn async/await to synchronous style.

Comment: Still, not making much sense.

Comment: Need more information. What are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you asking whether it's valid to use the `await` and `async` keywords together? Or is your question more whether you can use an anonymous `Task` object in this way?

Comment: It is to use the await and async keywords together.

Comment: @sof One must already always use them together.  You can only `await` in an `async `method.

Comment: What do you expect from "turn async/await to synchronous style."? Because accepted answer does not make anything synchronous...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov He also commented that `await Task.Run(async () => { /* .... */ })` is possible.  However, it will contradicte async/await single-thread model if a new thread is spawned.

Comment: @sof - "async/await single-thread model"? Not really sure what you mean. `await` let you write code that look like statements executed sequentially, but says absolutely nothing about threading...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov "The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. " according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: @sof I see what you mean... I'd personally not use "single-threaded" as synonym for "not creating new threads"...

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you want to define an anonymous asynchronous task.

You may do the following:

```
var taskAction = Task.Run(() => { /* .... */ });
var actionResult = await taskAction;

var taskFunction = Task.Run(async () => {
    var innerTask = someInnerTask();
    // Do something
    var innerTaskResult = await innerTask;
    // Handle result
    return someValue;
});
var functionResult = await taskFunction;
```

Alternatively, you may do:

```
var actionResult = await Task.Run(() => { /* .... */ });
var functionResult = await Task.Run(() => { /* .... */ return someValue; });
```

Please note that both action and function delegates do not receive any input arguments, and in case of a function, it must return a **Task** or **Task<>** instance.

Comment: Can we `await Task.Run(async () => { /* .... */ });`?

Comment: @sof, yes you can, as long as you also await some inner task in your anonymous delegate

Comment: Does `Task.Run(async () => { /* .... */ });` spawn a new thread?

Comment: @sof Not necessarily, it simply queues the task on the ThreadPool. The ThreadPool is a powerful API that share and recycle threads for better performance. It **doesn't mean it's going to create one**, though.

Comment: If async/await w/o Task.run never uses ThreadPool, `await Task.Run(async () => { /* .... */ });` isn't optimal to me.

Comment: @sof async/await uses the ThreadPool too.